# Bad state: add Fetch Article was called without a registered event handler

Tags: flutter

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late ArticleBloc articleBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    articleBloc = BlocProvider.of<ArticleBloc>(context);
    articleBloc.add(FetchArticlesEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

It works before but now the code wasn't working.

I try a lot to search but I failed.

This is the error:

> Bad state: add(FetchArticlesEvent) was called without a registered event handler.

Comment: Show me the code and model

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks to reponse Sir ! (y)
This is the code.

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late ArticleBloc articleBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    articleBloc = BlocProvider.of<ArticleBloc>(context);
    articleBloc.add(FetchArticlesEvent()); // this is the cuase of error
  }

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, or post code in comments. Use the [edit] link in your question.

Comment: Are you using mapEventToState in FetchArticlesEvent?

Answer (score 23):

What is your bloc version? Maybe you are using v8.0.0

At the mention [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=packagebloc-1). and the author's [proposal](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2526) for replacement.

> In bloc v7.2.0, mapEventToState was deprecated in favor of on. mapEventToState will be removed in bloc v8.0.0.

So please check your bloc version

Answer (score 11):

You have to register the FetchArticlesEvent class as follows. If you try to use an event that you have not registered, you will get this error.

```
class ArticleBloc extends Bloc<ArticleEvent, ArticleState> {
  ArticleBloc() : super(ArticleInitial()) {
    on<FetchArticlesEvent>((event, emit) {
      //TODO
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error in this code.

```
void onLogin() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    final email = emailController.text.trim();
    final password = passwordController.text.trim();
    final loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
    loginBloc.add(
      LoginButtonPressed(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      ),
    );
  }
```

and it was because I forgot to add event handler in LoginBloc.

**Before:**

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  LoginBloc() : super(LoginInitial());

  loginUser(Emitter<LoginState> emit, LoginEvent event) async {
    emit(LoginLoading());
    Response response;
    try {
      if (event is LoginButtonPressed) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
        response = await UserAuth.userLogin(
            email: event.email, password: event.password);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          if (response.data["role"] == "CUSTOMER") {
            SharedPreferencesUtils.setUserToken(
                token: response.data["access_token"]);
            emit(LoginSuccess());
          } else {
            emit(LoginFailure(message: "Invalid Credentials."));
          }
        } else {
          emit(LoginFailure(message: response.data["message"].toString()));
          print('from try');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is DioException) {
        if (e.type == DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout) {
          emit(LoginFailure(message: e.toString()));
        } else if (e.response != null) {
          String error = e.response?.data["message"];
          emit(LoginFailure(message: error));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**After**

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  LoginBloc() : super(LoginInitial()) {

    // event handler was added

    on<LoginEvent>((event, emit) async {
      await loginUser(emit, event);
    });
  }

  loginUser(Emitter<LoginState> emit, LoginEvent event) async {
    emit(LoginLoading());
    Response response;
    try {
      if (event is LoginButtonPressed) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
        response = await UserAuth.userLogin(
            email: event.email, password: event.password);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          if (response.data["role"] == "CUSTOMER") {
            SharedPreferencesUtils.setUserToken(
                token: response.data["access_token"]);
            emit(LoginSuccess());
          } else {
            emit(LoginFailure(message: "Invalid Credentials."));
          }
        } else {
          emit(LoginFailure(message: response.data["message"].toString()));
          print('from try');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is DioException) {
        if (e.type == DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout) {
          emit(LoginFailure(message: e.toString()));
        } else if (e.response != null) {
          String error = e.response?.data["message"];
          emit(LoginFailure(message: error));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a higher version of **bloc package**, then downgrade it to **7.0.0**

This solution helped me.

```
flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error **even after registering the event** in the bloc. Then I just **restarted the app** and it worked. This was just a silly mistake. I am beginner though.

My flutter_bloc ver: 8.1.3,  while I was working on my project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35547453)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You have to register the FetchArticlesEvent class as follows. If you try to use an event that you have not registered, you will get this error.